# How to select data from specific partition in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw, data-partitioning

How to select data from specific partition in DB2, something similar to

```
select * from table_name_partitioned partition (partition_name);
```

in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DATAPARTITIONNUM scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0021352.html).